# Google App Engineer, I can not find my css and js files by config static_dir

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, app.yaml

my files directories is:

```
helloboard:
|--bower_components
|   |--jquery
|         |--lotsof.js
|--css
|   |--app.css
|--js
|   |--app.js
|   |--someother.js
|--app.yaml
|--index.html
|--main.py
```

My app.yaml is:

```
application: helloboard
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:


- url: /.*
  script: main.app

- url: /css/*
  static_dir: css
  expiration: "364d"

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /bower_components
  static_dir: bower_components
```

when I visit http://localhost:8080/css/app.css
It is still 404 not find error.
I read https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig
But still do not know where my error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have as your **first** handler:

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

that will match **any** URL that's requested and send it to `main.app` -- no other handler is ever consulted!

Just move that stanza to the **end** of your `handlers:` section in `app.yaml`, and you should be fine.